# Illustrative datasets and analysis for multilevel modelling

Tags: r, stata, multilevel-analysis, epidemiology

I recently took an introductory course on multilevel modelling. Most of the datasets and examples we used were from the social sciences. I've just got a 2 week internship in a biostatistics department, where they want me to start a project concerning the variation at hospital level of patient outcomes for an emergency condition that has a high mortality rate, both between hospitals and over a 5 year time span. I'm starting the internship next week, and I was hoping to find a book or online resource where a similar analysis (preferably with R, Stata or MLwiN) has been done, preferably one where they provide their data sets for the reader. Any links would be most welcome.

Edit: I will be working with a dataset detailing all recorded aspects of the patient's in-hospital care. The main outcome of interest is death within 30 days of admission.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to check out the [UCLA multilevel modelling resources](http://statcomp.ats.ucla.edu/mlm/).

For example, the UCLA site has

- [this page](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/examples/mlm_ma_snijders/default.htm) that includes datafiles and analysis for several examples from Snijders and Bosker using multiple analysis packages.
- This copy of [Harvey Goldstein's multilevel modelling text with data files](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/examples/msm_goldstein/default.htm)

Answer (score 7):

Are you aware of the online resources at the MLwiN site? In particular [their free online course](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/course.html). They go through examples in all three software packages you mention (R, Stata, and MLwiN of course), and provide datasets along with them.

One of the modules goes through [multi-level models for binary responses](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/course-topics.html#m07), which it sounds like your project would entail.

Currently our [mixed-model](/questions/tagged/mixed-model) tag wiki has the [community suggested readings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/mixed-model/info) for multi-level models. Although I couldn't say off-hand which of those books had accompanying data.

Comment: Thanks - I have looked at the bristol.ac.uk course and it was quite helpful. However, at this stage I'm really looking for some analysis of patient & hospital data, and unfortunately all their examples (that I saw) were from the social sciences.

Comment: As for the books in the tag, I have Venables and Ripley (2002) and Gelman & Hill (2006) and haven't found anything there. I also just got Pinheiro & Bates - Mixed Effects Models in S and S-Plus from the library - there are a some pharmacokinetics datasets there, but nothing very close to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Stata comes with a bunch of toy data sets that you can take a look at: File -> Example Data Sets -> Manual datasets -> [XT] -> there appears to be some biostat data under `xtmepoisson` and `xtmixed`. There are some examples on GLLAMM website with both code and data: http://gllamm.org/examples.html.